# JSON Request from swift front-end being parsed with extra field on node back-end

Tags: swift, express

I use the following (swift) code to send a POST request with a json with a topic field and a post field to my node api.

```
        let newPost = NewPost(topic: topicField.text!, post: textPostField.text!)
        let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newPost)
        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData!, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(jsonString as Any)
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/newpost")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
                }
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
                print(responseJSON as Any)
                }
        
            let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print(decodedData as Any)
        }
        task.resume()
```

The json appears in the console in xcode with the correct format, as seen below.

```
{"topic":"xxxx","post":"xxxx"}
```

I receive it in the api with this code.

```
app.post("/newpost", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const schema = Joi.object({
    topic: Joi.string(),
    post: Joi.string().required()
  })
  const result = schema.validate(req.body)
  if (result.error) {
    //res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
    console.log(result.error.details[0].message)
    return;
  }

  //insert into datebase
})
```

I think the issue is that the json object is for some reason being received with this weird extra field that makes it not able to validate. The console from this code will have something like this:

```
GET /getposts 304 19.993 ms - -
{ '{"topic":"xxxx","post":"xxxx"}': '' }
"post" is required
POST /newpost - - ms - -
```

So basically it looks like it does not validate then it times out. Additionally, nothing gets entered into the database. I have spent many hours trying to figure this out but really cant find anything. I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure from the example which body parsing method you are using on the Node.js side, but I'm guessing it's [`bodyParser.urlencoded`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) based on the structure of `req.body`.

To ensure that the JSON is dealt with in the cleanest manner you'll need to:

- indicate the payload of the request is JSON from the client side
- parse the JSON body appropriately on the server side

#### Client side

You can add the appropriate `Content-Type` header from the client side using [`URLRequest.setValue(_:forHTTPHeaderField:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlrequest/2011447-setvalue) like so:

```
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

#### Server side

Update the body parser to [`bodyParser.json`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) like so:

```
const { json } = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(json());
...
app.post('/newpost', (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

Once I've done both these things, the `req.body` is an object on the server side as expected (`{ topic: 'foo', post: 'bar' }`) and passes the `Joi` validation.

Comment: Wow you're truly a god send. Thank you so much for the help.